# Segmentation fault when scanf to array of strucs (CORRECTED)

Tags: c, arrays

This classic example of student management is making me crazy
I have to accomplish scanf to an array of structs
After the first scanf i get segmentation fault.
Im almost sure i need to malloc something 
but ive been struggling with this since yesterday and i really need help
The problem in the %d scanf was my mistake editing the program to post it here..
Now i managed to post it complete..

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int cantidadalumnos = 50;
const int cantidadmaterias = 300;
struct AlumnoData
{
    int padron;
    int dni;
    char apellido[20];
    char nombres[20];
    int edad;
    char dir[30];
    char localidad [20];
    char provincia [20];
    int ingreso;
    int codcar;
};
struct MateriaData
{
    int codmat;
    char Materia[20];
    int anio;
    int cuat;
    int numcurso [20];
    int nota;
    int libro;
    int folio;
};
int main()
{
    int indicealumno;
    indicealumno = 0;
    int indicemateria;
    struct AlumnoData alumno[cantidadalumnos];
    struct MateriaData materia [cantidadmaterias];
    char opcion;
    int intop;
    do
    {
        printf ("\n\n\n\n\n\n\#####      Gestion de alumnos      #####\n/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / /");
        printf ("\n  1. Ingresar alumno");
        printf ("\n  2. Buscar un alumno por padron");
        opcion = getch();
        intop = opcion;
        switch (intop)
        {
        case '1' :
            printf ("-------------INGRESO DE ALUMNO\n---------------------------\n");

            for (indicealumno = 0 ; indicealumno<cantidadalumnos; indicealumno++)
            {
                printf("La cantidad de alumnos hasta el momento es de %d de %d", indicealumno, cantidadalumnos);
                printf("\nPadron:");
                scanf("%d", alumno[indicealumno].padron);
                break;
            };
            break;
        }
    }
    while (opcion !=27);
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you want the `break` in `case '1'` outside of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%d` format string is used to read an `int` but you are trying to read a *character string*. Try changing the format string to the correct `%s` instead. Note that I've also included a *width* specifier to avoid an input buffer overrun.

```
scanf("%19s", alumno[stdindex].name);
```

**Edit for updated question:**

The `scanf()` function needs the address of the variables that are to receive values. That allows the function to modify the variable's contents. The line where you read a `padron` value should be:

```
scanf("%d", &alumno[indicealumno].padron);
```

Note the `&` (address-of) operator added before the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
scanf("%s",alumno[stdindex].name);
```

because name is character array and you most probably consider a name as string so `%s` should be used instead of `%d`.

use `fgets` for better result. Thanx to @mafso

Comment: Encouraging people to use `scanf("%s"...` is definitely not a good thing…

Comment: that i know but most probably user knows the side effects of scanf.

Comment: The side effect of UB if a user enters more than 19 characters without a whitespace? Suggest `fgets` instead…

Comment: Yes I know that scanf exits on any whitespace character whether it is a space.

Comment: Corrected, the mistake on the scanf was not the main issue.. The main issue is Segmentation Fault memory allocation and i think i have to use malloc.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing `scanf` with `getch`. So after calling `scanf` (which requires you to hit Return), there is still a Return character in the input stream. Assuming there are no other extra characters in the input stream, it may be enough to call `getch` again after `scanf` to eat the Return character.

A more manageable solution is to use `scanf("%d", &opcion)` and change the `case '1':` to `case 1:`. Or you can use `scanf("%c")` with a `char` variable.

Edit: I think Blastfurnace has identified your current problem. But this issue I raise will cause you trouble soon.